# Typescript: Typing Function Return Type based on Parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if there is way to type the return of a function based on the input given to it. Here is an example of what I am thinking:

```
function toEnum(...strings: string[]) {
  const enumObject = {};

  strings.forEach((str) => {
    enumObject[str.toUpperCase()] = str;
  });

  return enumObject;
}

const myEnum = toEnum('one', 'two', 'three')
```

Is there a way to type this function so that we know that `myEnum` looks like:

```
{
  ONE: 'one',
  TWO: 'two',
  THREE: 'three'
}
```

edit:

as @dariosicily mentioned, we could type `enumObject` using a `Record<string, string>` or index signatures, but I am wondering if there is a way to know the actual keys present in the return object based on the params passed in.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAja8W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I thought it may be mapped types, but couldnt quite get there.

Comment: @jcalz would there be a way to add logic like this?

`const myEnum = toEnum('twoWords')`, then referenced like `myEnum.TWO_WORDS`

Comment: yes, but that expands the scope of the question so I'm not sure it's appropriate here (I see `str.toUpperCase()` in your question and not anything that would turn `"twoWords"` into `"TWO_WORDS"`).  I'm worried that if I [add that](https://tsplay.dev/WYv5bw) you'll ask for a third thing.  Please stabilize the question so I can answer it.

Comment: That was the extent of my question. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer; could you [edit] the question to include the need for transforming the keys from lowerCamelCase  to UPPER_CASE (aka SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an intrinsic `Uppercase<T>` string manipulation utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype) which, when given a `string` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) as input, produces an uppercase version as output.  So `Uppercase<"abc">` and `"ABC"` are the same type.  Using this type we can create a [mapped type with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to express the output type of `toEnum()`, given the [union of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) the string literal types of its arguments:

```
function toEnum<K extends string>(...strings: K[]): { [P in K as Uppercase<P>]: P } {
    const enumObject: any = {};

    strings.forEach((str) => {
        enumObject[str.toUpperCase()] = str;
    });

    return enumObject;
}
```

Note that `toEnum()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the union of the element types of the `strings` array.  Note that `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` so that `strings` is indeed an array of strings, and because this constraint gives the compiler a hint that we want to infer string literal types for its elements instead of just `string`.  You definitely need to use generic here, otherwise you'd just get `Record<string, string>` out of the function.

The type `{[P in K as Uppercase<P>]: P}` iterates over every string `P` in the original `K` union and remaps it to an uppercase version as the key, and then uses just the same type `P` as the value.  That's the type you wanted.

Also note that I gave `enumObject` [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) so as to opt out of strict type checking inside the implementation of `toEnum()`; the compiler is unable to follow the logic that `enumObject[str.toUpperCase()]=str` will be an appropriate operation on a value of type `{[P in K as Uppercase<P>]: P}`, so we won't even make it try.

Anyway you can test that it does what you want:

```
const myEnum = toEnum('one', 'two', 'three', "fortyFive");
/* const myEnum: {
    ONE: "one";
    TWO: "two";
    THREE: "three";
    FORTYFIVE: "fortyFive";
} */

console.log(myEnum.THREE) // "three" both at compile and runtime
```

---

In the comments you mentioned that for something like `fortyFive`, you'd like the key to be `FORTY_FIVE` instead of `FORTYFIVE`.  That is, you don't just want the key to be an uppercase version of the input.  You want the input to be interpreted as lower [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and the output to be all-upper [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (also known as SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE).

This is also possible in TypeScript, using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to split a string literal type into characters, and [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to operate on these characters programmatically.

First let's do it at the type level:

```
type LowerPascalToUpperSnake<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? LowerPascalToUpperSnake<R,
        `${A}${F extends Lowercase<F> ? "" : "_"}${Uppercase<F>}`
    > : A;
```

Note that it is useful to have a function that does the same thing at the value level:

```
function lowerPascalToUpperSnake<T extends string>(str: T) {
    return str.split("").map(
        c => (c === c.toLowerCase() ? "" : "_") + c.toUpperCase()
    ).join("") as LowerPascalToUpperSnake<T>
}
```

Both the type and the function behave similarly; the idea is to iterate over each character of the string, insert an underscore if and only if the current character is not lowercase, and then insert an uppercase version of the current character.
You can verify that this works:

```
const test = lowerPascalToUpperSnake("abcDefGhiJklmNop");
// const test: "ABC_DEF_GHI_JKLM_NOP"
console.log(test); // "ABC_DEF_GHI_JKLM_NOP"
```

The value at runtime and the type computed by the compiler agree.

And now we can use the "lower-Pascal-to-upper-snake" operation in `toEnum()` instead of the original uppercase operation:

```
function toEnum<K extends string>(...strings: K[]): 
  { [P in K as LowerPascalToUpperSnake<P>]: P } {
    const enumObject: any = {};

    strings.forEach((str) => {
        enumObject[lowerPascalToUpperSnake(str)] = str;
    });

    return enumObject;
}
```

And see it in action:

```
const myEnum = toEnum('one', 'two', 'three', "fortyFive");
/* const myEnum: {
    ONE: "one";
    TWO: "two";
    THREE: "three";
    FORTY_FIVE: "fortyFive";
} */

console.log(myEnum.FORTY_FIVE) // "fortyFive"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoIgSADMBXYeAFwwHtgkb6BRYCsAHgGkkIAHjQjAAJlCRQamYFgB8ACgB0KqTKxQAXEh4BtALoBKbbiS6ACkgxM+ICQFUYMCGnh2IXc3P3bLAXzxSEnhGKX4OMBQAIwArCFptEGAATyQAXjw-AG4iILVrDSUyejRWBAALBQU1Q3S5QMISJpFOaLjaXTUlFkdnNABhdwVDfXTJaRzGkj9DSaC0CBoKNCYWyNj4mknp3MaQ4DCwZPZOMZYTsAUAckYIK4AaJCuaAHd6B6eacoW7x4AiYpoGjJABiGAAbhA-rNSAB6ABUSH2h2OERMQRQADlWNo-rc-tsSAAVADqKFxr3oBKCRIAEgAlVg4pB-L4-alTEEoelEgCaIIAkgA1ZkAkrAsGQjnTJDw2G7YKhegAGwgSmV9CwCiOFyUdMZrFqsNhLLZEChSCi9C+SBANCR9DAMAwqttYiQaCodEguz8u1AkFgCGQAGV4AtwAUQ6AANbIAjERqUah0RjMNgRXj8IQicTjdSKFRKfKyLQ6AzGPBmSzWHS2iQAGXoLxc5jsbmVRPovRc0ZAcc83l8SACCaayPtazam0SKTGuGyCpIJcKgLK8Eq1WktTS9THzQi046GpbaDbUA7XZ7aD7ca3aBGYzUhJmcymCyWK3CrQ2tG2fsTEhgWcJAm1Pc9L27Jxe1jDwiWzYQxAkFdHgAQQQ3NkOkAoxj+P56jSGkMKQpAAAMABJcGsMgXCQEE-Eo6jaPpPxSKQAB+UDm1bdsQE7KC+lvDx6XuIISAo3BUIY3AQWIvMwJcNwoA8EF6k4vCkFxAB9P5pOvJSVLkVignqbRULfUhk1oBgmBPHiLz4q9oJvWCuHgwRELzFdFDUbQiVqfcP2WJgulgZUMBoBQ8MMJQwBAGAFDE+A6iQBRkrSDKkW6egFIGIZanUv5NJZHTagAaiynpnMGZThiCGKYnoawouhesuPA3j+OvIS3LkUgANICdmGge0Mjss9OqcwTYKikAongAARCAyAAcXKDAACkY2VMBMXoGBoW2Y0HQOe1hCkXFUIAIX6LSFtYEEtJW2kBS0jaeAbABZLTMRQcw-kGpVVXVTUFHOmhZiQY6-mu277se57Xver6fr+oqFSGnUIjODNOGuW4PmeN5CbNX4WUBCUIShGFGgRE6UQudEpixUV8UJUlyVNN5pWJBkmQpb5zR5rkeV5LTBRFXEKdBKnpQCOUMaBtUNS1LHOCUEW+XF4VDShk0xSBGWpSIPwgA)

Comment: `<K extends string>` Can you please explain this?

Comment: Lot of useful informations, in your opinion my alternative solution below with `Record` can be considered a valid alternative or it contains some specific flaws  ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @ArnavMishra I edited the answer to explain, although I'm not sure if you're just asking about [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions, or specifically about [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

Comment: @dariosicily that really depends on the use case; if, as the OP asked, you want the compiler to know that the *type* of the output is something like `{ONE: "one", TWO: "two"}`, then `Record<string, string>` is too wide.  If you don't care about strongly typing the output, then `Record<string, string>` is fine.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again for the feedback and time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that while in the javascript language the line `enumObject[str.toUpperCase()] = str;` assignment is legitimate with typescript the same line causes an error because you have not explicitely declared the index signature of the `enumObject` or explicitely declared it as `any`.

In this cases one way to solve the issue is use the builtin [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) utility type applying it to your `enumObject` like below:

```
function toEnum(...strings: string[]) {
    const enumObject: Record<string, string> = {};
    strings.forEach((str) => {
        enumObject[str.toUpperCase()] = str;
    });
    return enumObject;
}

const myEnum = toEnum('one', 'two', 'three')
//it will print { ONE: 'one', TWO: 'two', THREE: 'three' }
console.log(myEnum);
```

*Edit*: answering to the question

> there is a way to know the actual keys present in the return object
> based on the params passed in

You can use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?retiredLocale=it) method and return the keys as an `Array<string>`:

```
const myEnum = toEnum('one', 'two', 'three')
//it will print [ONE, TWO, THREE]
const keys = (Object.keys(myEnum) as Array<string>);
```

If you want to create a new type from keys you can use `typeof`:

```
const keys = (Object.keys(myEnum) as Array<string>);
//type KeysType = 'ONE' | 'TWO' | 'THREE'
type KeysType = typeof keys[number];
```

Comment: Ok, I should have been more thorough with my example. You're example works, but it just has `myEnum` as `Record<string, string>` as expected. I'm wondering if there is a way to type it so we know the exact keys inside of myEnum based on params.